# Creating downloadable backup of MySQL

Tags: mysql, servlets

I am using the following codes to backup the current database. However this doesn't work. On calling this servlet, no response is coming !

```
 String executeCmd = "mysqldump -u root ultimate > c:/" + dateTime + ".sql";
    try   {
        Process p = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime ().exec("cmd / c"   + executeCmd);
        while (true) {
        if (p.waitFor () == 0) break; // until the end of the process, only to exit the loop
        }

        }   catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
        }
```

Also, after this I am trying to make the sql file downloadable using content-disposition header. Please suggest if it will be better to use

```
Select * into outfile ..
```

Comment: Do you want an sql file that can recreate the table structure and the data, or just like a tab separated dump of the data?

Comment: I want to recreate the table structure. Currently, the 'outfile' file doesn't allow me to do so. So, i guess 'mysqldump' is my only option? If yes, please help me fix this code!